# How to output large HTML chunk using JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jwplayer

hi all i am trying to output a large html chunk that holds opening and closing javascript tags. The javascript included is a jw player script and its mixed with javascript dynamic variable **+url** and php variable **$Title**. i tried document.write but the player didn't show up in the browser !instead it output part of the document.write statements! could you guys help me fix this issue ? Thanks in advance.

```
document.write("<html>");
document.write("<head>");
document.write("<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">");
document.write("</head>");
document.write("<br>");

document.write("Title:<?php echo $Title;?> <script type='text/javascript' src='./jwplayer.js'></script>");

document.write("<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>");
document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
document.write(" jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({");
document.write("'flashplayer': './player.swf',");

document.write("'file': + url,");

document.write("'autostart': 'true',");
document.write("'controlbar': 'bottom',");
document.write("'width': '470',");
document.write("'height': '320'");
document.write("});");
document.write("</script>");
document.write("</html>");
```

Comment: I would check line 3... document.write("<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">");

Comment: Why not output the javascript from PHP?

Answer (score 0):

PHP written into the document with JavaScript will not run. PHP is evaluated *before* a document is received by the browser. JavaScript runs *after*.

As far as writing out a `<script>` element dynamically without breaking the current script, one option is to escape the forward slash, i.e.

```
document.write("<\/script>");
```

But, is there a reason JS has to output this code? In addition to the above problems, `document.write` is a bit outdated, and can become problematic when writing scripts. It would be a lot cleaner to host a PHP page like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    Title: <?php echo $Title;?>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='./jwplayer.js'></script>

    <div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

      jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
        'flashplayer': './player.swf',
        'file': url,// assumes 'url' exists in the global namespace!
        'autostart': 'true',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '470',
        'height': '320'
       });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Note `<body>` tag added.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. Paislee i tried escape the forward slash but the player doesn't show in the browser. Paislee i know in php its much easier but want to do this in client side since parsing url value in server side puts lots of load on the server!

Comment: Your PHP variable won't work if you do this in the browser. Why write the script dynamically anyway? Instead of your `document.write`s, just use the markup from my answer.

Comment: If this code is inside a PHP script, which it seems like it is, it will work fine. The PHP variable will get replaced on the server side, and the resultant JS will get output to the browser. I do agree, though, i don't see a reason to do this with JS - the JS isn't doing anything here. Should just be PHP to HTML.

Comment: can you guys show me how i can use javascript variable instead of current media url ?jwplayer().load({file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/nPripu9l-60830.mp4'}) ? i want to use dynamic variable instead of above mp4? i tried current media url ?jwplayer().load({file: '+url'}) but it didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do but `document.getElementById("idtag").innerHTML = "Data";` will fill in the content between the tags of the element with the selected id.

Example:

```
<div id="dataplaceholder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("dataplaceholder").innerHTML = "<h2>Hello World!</h2>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Haxxed. Suppose i already have jw player in the page but value of file is empty. when we load our page 
a javascript parases the value of flv url and puts it in variable variable url. Now how i can use that value inside following line ?

'file': '+url', becomes ==> 'file': 'http://www.somesite.net/media/flv/12345.flv',

Comment: if the `url` variable is already set somewhere else in the javascript then it shouldn't be in quotes. It should look like:'file:' + url;